# Can I specify lumpsum investment that I have decided to make in this year, but not yet done

Tags: taxes, india, rebate

I live in India. If I have decided to perform investment of 50000 INR in this year in say ELSS. But I want to perform it as a lumpsum investment, instead of SIP. I want to spread the investment in 4 lump sum transactions. So I might do first purchase in April, next in July, 3rd in October and 4th in March (mainly based on the NAVs). Can I specify this, so that my tax will not be deducted itself and I dont have to claim any tax returns.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are talking about TDS by your employer. Yes this is possible. Check with your company for details, some require the declaration early and have a defined window for proof of investment.